# How to pass variable to express routes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm making a website where i need an id passed to an express route.
I have a button (id='approve_appln') which fetches a route. The javascript involved is as follows:

```
var appr_appln = document.getElementById('approve_appln');
appr_appln.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var approve_id = appr_appln.getAttribute('data');
  fetch('/approved', {method: 'POST'})
    .then(function(response) {
      if(response.ok) {
        alert(approve_id);

        return;
      }
      throw new Error('Request failed.');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      alert('error');
    });
});
```

I need to pass the **approve_id** variable to the **/approved** route. The route is now empty though:

```
app.post('/approved',function(req,res){


});
```

How do I pass the **approve_id** variable so it can be used to refer a particular object in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endpoint can have an id attached to it 
for example:

```
app.post('/approved',function(req,res){


});
```

should be

```
app.post('/approved/:id',function(req,res){
  const id = req.params.id // This is how you access URL variable
});
```

Keep in mind `:id` here is a variable that can be replaced by an actual ID when requesting from URL.
for example you can do something like this ```http://localhost/approved/1231451324123

so to follow your example, you can just send the  ID with the URL by doing something like this

```
var appr_appln = document.getElementById('approve_appln');
appr_appln.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var approve_id = appr_appln.getAttribute('data');
  fetch(`/approved/${approve_id}`, {method: 'POST'})
    .then(function(response) {
      if(response.ok) {
        alert(approve_id);

        return;
      }
      throw new Error('Request failed.');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      alert('error');
    });
});
```

note I only changed this line `fetch('/approved', {method: 'POST'})`
I replaced single quotes `'` with ` so I can concatenate easier. also `${}` means I can add any CODE inside these brackets.

Good luck, if you need more explanation let me know.